About the units in $\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1+\sqrt{d}}{2}]$
Let's consider $K=\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{d}]$ where $d$ is positive and square free. It is well known that the ring of integers is
$$
{O}_{K}=\mathbb{Z}\left[\frac{1+\sqrt{d}}{2}\right]
$$ if $d=1 \mod 4$ and just $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}]$ otherwise. it is obvious that
$$
\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}]\subseteq \mathbb{Z}\left[\frac{1+\sqrt{d}}{2}\right].
$$
Also, it is well-known that $\alpha$ is a unit of $O_{K}$ iff $N(\alpha)=\pm 1$. Now let's consider $\alpha=\frac{x+y\sqrt{d}}{2}$: then $N(\alpha)=\pm 1$ means $x^2-dy^2=\pm4$
We can see that if $d=1 \mod 8$, then $x$ cannot be odd, which means that the units in $\mathbb{Z}\left[\frac{1+\sqrt{d}}{2}\right]$ are precisely those in  $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}]$.
Questions:

What if $d=5$ mod8, does the odd solution to the diophantine equation always exists? i.e. are there always units in  $\mathbb{Z}\left[\frac{1+\sqrt{d}}{2}\right]$ that are not in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}]$?
What are the units in $\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1+\sqrt{d}}{2}]$,when $d=5 \mod8$?


Please use a high-level tag like "nt.number-theory". I added this tag now. Regarding high-level tags, see https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/1075/

I don't have enough reputation to write an answer, so this is a comment. In the article "Lattice minima and units in real quadratic number fields" by Daniel C. Mayer (https://publi.math.unideb.hu/load_doc.php?p=4160&t=abs), they prove (Theorem 4.4) that if the class number of a real quadratic number field $\mathbb Q(\sqrt d)$, $d \equiv 5 \pmod 8$ is not divisible by $3$, then there exists a "half-unit" if and only if there is a cubic number field with discriminant $4d$.

Regarding (i): No, not always. $37$ is $5 \bmod 8$, and the primitive unit in $\mathbb{Z}[(1+\sqrt{37})/2]$ is $6+\sqrt{37}$. In this example, $x^2-d y^2=-1$; the first case I can find with $x^2-d y^2 = 1$ and $x$, $y \in \mathbb{Z}$ is $d=141$, with $95+8 \sqrt{141}$ as the fundamental unit.
(ii) I don't know what sort of answer to give. The units are $\pm \left( \tfrac{x+y \sqrt{d}}{2} \right)^n$ where $(x,y)$ is the smallest solution to $x^2-d y^2 = \pm 4$. Sometimes this smallest solution is even and sometimes it is odd.

Many thanks for your counter-example for (i)! Since (i) is not true, my (ii) doesnt make sence. Thanks a lot for your help

I was just rereading this answer, and I'm not sure that I believe my $2$-adic computation any more. I'll try to fix it.

Yeah, deleting all that. I'm pretty sure it was broken.

At the 2022 Western Number Theory meeting, Michael Beeson asked the question, when $d\equiv5\bmod8$, what are conditions for the fundamental unit to be in ${\bf Z}[\sqrt d]$. https://oeis.org/A107997 tabulates squarefree integers $m$ congruent to $5$ modulo $8$ such that the minimal solution of the Pell equation $x^2 - my^2 = \pm4$ has both $x$ and $y$ odd. https://oeis.org/A107998 tabulates squarefree integers $m$ for which the fundamental unit of ${\bf Q}(\sqrt m)$ is of the form $u + v\sqrt m$ for integer $u, v$.   https://oeis.org/A000924/a000924.pdf has much information about the problem.
Florian Breuer recommended the following reading:
P. Stevenhagen, On a problem of Eisenstein, Acta Arith. 74 (3) (1996) 259–268, https://eudml.org/doc/206851.
F. Breuer, Periods of Ducci sequences and odd solutions to a Pellian equation, Bull. Austral. Math. Soc. 100 (2) (2019) 201–205, https://carmamaths.org/florianbreuer/DucciPell_baustms_v2.pdf.
F. Breuer, Multiplicative orders of Gauss periods and the arithmetic of real quadratic fields, Finite Fields Appl. 73 (2021), https://carmamaths.org/florianbreuer/MultiplicativeOrders_v5.pdf.
Here is a link to the slides from Florian's talk, Parity of fundamental units, at Number Theory Down Under, 4 September 2023:
https://maths.anu.edu.au/sites/prod.maths.sca-lws06.anu.edu.au/files/Breuer-NTDU2023.pdf

The page https://mathworld.wolfram.com/FundamentalUnit.html has a table of fundamental units, with $D$ there in the role of your $d$. When $D = 37$ the table has David Speyer's example $6+\sqrt{37}$. Looking at all other $D \equiv 5 \bmod 8$ in that table, there is one more counterexample to your question (i): at $D = 101$ there is $10 + \sqrt{101}$. Seeing both of these revealed a pattern: $37 = 6^2 + 1$ and $101 = 10^2+1$. When $m$ is twice an odd number, $m^2 + 1 \equiv 5 \bmod 8$.
Theorem. When $m$ is twice an odd number and $d := m^2+1$, the fundamental unit in $\mathbf Z[(1+\sqrt{d})/2]$ is in $\mathbf Z[\sqrt{d}]$ except when $d = 5$.
The choice $d = 5$ really is an exception since $\mathbf Z[(1+\sqrt{5})/2]$ has fundamental unit $(1+\sqrt{5})/2$.
Remark. I am not assuming $m^2+1$ is squarefree, so $\mathbf Z[(1+\sqrt{m^2+1})/2]$ may not be the full ring of integers in $\mathbf Q(\sqrt{m^2+1})$. It is definitely not a square, and since $m^2+1 \equiv 1 \bmod 4$ when $m$ is even, the set $\mathbf Z[(1+\sqrt{m^2+1})/2]$ is a ring of rank $2$ over $\mathbf Z$ containing the subring $\mathbf Z[\sqrt{m^2+1}]$ with index $2$ and both have unit groups with rank $1$ by properties of Pell's equation.
The numbers $m^2+1$ where $m$ is twice an odd number are both squarefree and not squarefree infinitely often. To explain that, write values of $m^2+1$ when $m$ is twice an odd number as values of $(2(2n+1))^2+1 = 16n^2 + 16n + 5$ when $n$ is an integer. Every irreducible quadratic in $\mathbf Z[x]$ whose values on $\mathbf Z$ include  at least one squarefree value has squarefree values at a positive density of $n \geq 1$ and this density is between $0$ and $1$.  That is a 1933 theorem of G. Ricci (not the G. Ricci in geometry, who died in 1928). A precise statement of this theorem is equation (4) here. And Rudnick's notes discuss the general problem of squarefree values of polynomials in $\mathbf Z[x]$
Now let's prove the theorem.
Proof. When $d \equiv 1 \bmod 4$ and is not a square, the elements of
$\mathbf Z[(1+\sqrt{d})/2]$ are $(x+y\sqrt{d})/2$ where $x \equiv y \bmod 2$. A nice property when $d \equiv 5 \bmod 8$ (a strict subset of the numbers that are $1 \bmod 4$) is that every element of $\mathbf Z[(1+\sqrt{d})/2]$ has its cube in $\mathbf Z[\sqrt{d}]$. That is a pure calculation: letting $\alpha = (x+y\sqrt{d})/2$ where $x \equiv y \bmod 2$, to prove $\alpha^3 \in \mathbf Z[\sqrt{d}]$ we may suppose $\alpha\not\in \mathbf Z[\sqrt{d}]$, so take $x$ and $y$ to be odd. Using the binomial theorem,
$$
\left(\frac{x+y\sqrt{d}}{2}\right)^3 = \frac{x(x^2+3dy^2) + y(3x^2+dy^2)\sqrt{d}}{8}.
$$
Since $x$ and $y$ are odd, $x^2$ and $y^2$ are $1 \bmod 8$. Since $d \equiv 5 \bmod 8$,
$$
x^2 + 3dy^2 \equiv 1 + 3d \equiv 1 + 3(5) \equiv 0 \bmod 8, \ 
3x^2 + dy^2 \equiv 3 + d \equiv 0 \bmod 8.
$$
Thus $((x+y\sqrt{d})/2)^3 \in \mathbf Z [\sqrt{d}]$.
When $m \in \mathbf Z^+$, the ring $\mathbf Z[\sqrt{m^2+1}]$ has fundamental unit $m + \sqrt{m^2+1}$.  Here is a proof for those who know about continued fractions and their link to Pell's equation:  the continued fraction of $\sqrt{m^2+1}$ is $[m,2m,2m,2m,\ldots]$ and the very first convergent $m/1$ leads to a solution $(x,y) = (m,1)$ of $x^2 - (m^2+1)y^2 = -1$. This result can also be proved by other methods, such as Theorem 7.5 and Example 7.7 here.
When $d = m^2 + 1$ with $m$ being twice an odd number, assume there is a unit in $A := \mathbf Z[(1+\sqrt{d})/2]$ that is not in $B :=\mathbf Z[\sqrt{d}]$. We will show $d = 5$ (equivalently, $m = 2$). Let $u > 1$ be the fundamental unit of $A$. Since $u \not\in B$ while $u^3 \in B$ (because $d \equiv 5 \bmod 8$; see the first paragraph of this proof), in $A^\times/B^\times$ the order of $u$ is $3$.  We have $u^k = m + \sqrt{m^2+1}$ for some $k > 1$, so $u^k$ is trivial in $A^\times/B^\times$.
That implies $3 \mid k$. Write $k = 3\ell$, so
$$
m + \sqrt{m^2+1} = u^k = u^{3\ell} = v^3
$$
where $v = u^\ell$.  Thus $m + \sqrt{m^2+1}$ is the cube of a unit in $A$. Write $v = (x+y\sqrt{d})/2$ where $x \equiv y \bmod 2$. Then
$$
m + \sqrt{m^2 + 1} = m+\sqrt{d} = \left(\frac{x+y\sqrt{d}}{2}\right)^3 = \frac{x(x^2+3dy^2) + y(3x^2+dy^2)\sqrt{d}}{8}.
$$
Looking at the coefficients of $\sqrt{d}$, $8 = y(3x^2 + dy^2)$, so $y$ is positive. Since $d = m^2 + 1 \geq 5$, $8 \geq dy^3 \geq 5y^3$, so necessarily $y = 1$ and $d = 5$ (the next value of $d = m^2 + 1$ after $5$ where $m$ is twice an odd number is $37$, which is too big).
QED

Note that $d=m^2+1$ is not a necessary condition. $141\equiv5\bmod8$, and the corresponding fundamental unit is $95+8\sqrt{141}$.
